Spring @RestController and @PathVariable queuing bug?
I've noticed some odd behavior with my SpringBoot micro service. I'm using spring mvc, springboot 3.3.3 and Java 21.
Consider the following code in a Controller (annotated with @RestController and lombok's @Slf4j):
@GetMapping("/test/{id}")
public void getTest(@PathVariable Integer id) {
  log.info("get test: {}", id);
}

@DeleteMapping("/test/{id}")
public void deleteTest(@PathVariable Integer id) throws InterruptedException  {
  TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(10);
  log.info("delete test: {}", id);
}

@GetMapping("/test/{id}/something")
public void getTestSomething(@PathVariable Integer id) throws InterruptedException {
  TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(10);
  log.info("get test something: {}", id);
}


If I hit DELETE /test/3 followed by GET /test/3 within 10 seconds, the GET will wait until the DELETE request returns. However if I hit GET /test/3/something and then GET /test/3 it won't wait. The latter is the behavior I would expect for both.
Also, if I do a different id for DELETE and the first GET, the GET won't wait. For example, DELETE /test/4 followed by GET /test/3
Another interesting observation is that if I don't use the passed in path variable, e.g. just don't log it or pass it to anything, it won't wait. The same goes if the paths don't specify path variables and are equal. E.g: GET /test and DELETE /test
Also, if I include a @RequestParameter the waiting issue doesn't occur. E.g. GET /test/3?key=value
Is the weird waiting behavior I've observed expected? Or have I uncovered some strange bug?

I would expect none of this to wait unless a) there is only 1 thread in the  thread pool b) many requests have been made so the pool is drained - which is almost the same as a)

I would expect the same. I haven't modified the thread pool count so it's on the default 200. I also don't have anything making requests apart from the manual requests I detailed above. I'm a bit lost to be honest

What if, it is not a problem server but client problem? How are you making your requests??? EG, you mayb have single connection/path policy in which case CLIENT queues up requests with the same path.

I can't believe I didn't try that. Looks like the issue only happens in Swagger UI

So i guess thats the thing :)

Turns out that the problem was how I was making the queries. I was using Swagger UI.

Project Tree
demo
├── pom.xml
├── src
│   └── main
│       ├── java
│       │   └── com
│       │       └── example
│       │           ├── DemoApplication.java
│       │           └── HelloController.java
│       └── resources
│           ├── application.properties
│           └── logback.xml
├── test1.sh
├── test2.sh
├── test3.sh
├── test4.sh
├── test5.sh
├── test6.sh
└── test-main.sh

pom.xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>3.3.3</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>demo</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>demo</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

    <properties>
        <maven.compiler.source>17</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>17</maven.compiler.target>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-logging</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
    <finalName>app</finalName>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>

logback.xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
    <appender name="Console" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
        <encoder>
            <pattern>%d [%thread] %-5level %-50logger{40} - %msg%n</pattern>
        </encoder>
    </appender>
     
    <appender name="RollingFile" class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
        <file>app.log</file>
        <encoder>
            <pattern>%d [%thread] %-5level %-50logger{40} - %msg%n</pattern>
        </encoder>
         
        <rollingPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.SizeAndTimeBasedRollingPolicy">
            <fileNamePattern>app-%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.%i.log</fileNamePattern>
            <maxFileSize>1MB</maxFileSize>
            <maxHistory>30</maxHistory>
            <totalSizeCap>10MB</totalSizeCap>
            <cleanHistoryOnStart>true</cleanHistoryOnStart>
        </rollingPolicy>
    </appender>
     
    <root level="INFO">
        <appender-ref ref="Console" />
        <appender-ref ref="RollingFile" />
    </root>
</configuration>

DemoApplication.java
package com.example;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

@SpringBootApplication
public class DemoApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(DemoApplication.class, args);
    }

}

HelloController.java
I changed the return value of method to String and returned the corresponding date and time.
package com.example;

import lombok.extern.slf4j.Slf4j;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.*;

import java.time.LocalDateTime;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

@Slf4j
@RestController
public class HelloController {

    @GetMapping("/test/{id}")
    public String getTest(@PathVariable Integer id) {
        log.info("get test: {}", id);

        LocalDateTime now = LocalDateTime.now();
        DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS");
        String formattedDateTime = now.format(formatter);

        return formattedDateTime + "\t" + "get test: "+ id + "\n";
    }

    @DeleteMapping("/test/{id}")
    public String deleteTest(@PathVariable Integer id) throws InterruptedException {
        log.info("entry delete test: {}", id);
        TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(10);
        log.info("delete test: {}", id);

        LocalDateTime now = LocalDateTime.now();
        DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS");
        String formattedDateTime = now.format(formatter);

        return formattedDateTime + "\t" + "delete test: "+ id + "\n";
    }

    @GetMapping("/test/{id}/something")
    public String getTestSomething(@PathVariable Integer id) throws InterruptedException {
        log.info("entry get test something: {}", id);
        TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(10);
        log.info("get test something: {}", id);

        LocalDateTime now = LocalDateTime.now();
        DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS");
        String formattedDateTime = now.format(formatter);

        return formattedDateTime + "\t" + "get test something: "+ id  +"\n";
    }

}

Test Shell Script

test-main.sh call test1.sh, test2.sh, test3.sh, test4.sh, test5.sh, test6.sh

test1.sh (test4.sh) call getTest

test2.sh (test5.sh) call deleteTest

test3.sh (test6.sh) call getTestSomething


test-main.sh
#!/bin/bash
echo "TEST MAIN START"
start_time0=$(date +%s)



for i in {1..6}; do
  ./test${i}.sh &
done

wait

end_time0=$(date +%s)

elapsed_time0=$((end_time0 - start_time0))

echo "TEST MAIN - Elapsed time: $elapsed_time0 seconds"

test1.sh
#!/bin/bash
echo "TEST 1 START"
start_time1=$(date +%s)


for i in {1..100}; do
  curl -X GET "http://localhost:8080/test/${i}"  &
done

wait

end_time1=$(date +%s)

elapsed_time1=$((end_time1 - start_time1))

echo "TEST 1 - Elapsed time: $elapsed_time1 seconds"

test2.sh
#!/bin/bash
echo "TEST 2 START"
start_time2=$(date +%s)

for i in {1..100}; do
  curl -X DELETE "http://localhost:8080/test/${i}"  &
done

wait

end_time2=$(date +%s)

elapsed_time2=$((end_time2 - start_time2))

echo "TEST 2 - Elapsed time: $elapsed_time2 seconds"

test3.sh
#!/bin/bash
echo "TEST 3 START"
start_time3=$(date +%s)

for i in {1..100}; do
  curl -X GET "http://localhost:8080/test/${i}/something" &
done

wait

end_time3=$(date +%s)

elapsed_time3=$((end_time3 - start_time3))

echo "TEST 3 - Elapsed time: $elapsed_time3 seconds"

test4.sh
#!/bin/bash
echo "TEST 4 START"
start_time4=$(date +%s)

for i in {1..100}; do
  curl -X GET "http://localhost:8080/test/${i}"  &
done

wait

end_time4=$(date +%s)

elapsed_time4=$((end_time4 - start_time4))

echo "TEST 4 - Elapsed time: $elapsed_time4 seconds"


test5.sh
#!/bin/bash
echo "TEST 5 START"
start_time5=$(date +%s)

for i in {1..100}; do
  curl -X DELETE "http://localhost:8080/test/${i}"  &
done

wait

end_time5=$(date +%s)

elapsed_time5=$((end_time5 - start_time5))

echo "TEST 5 - Elapsed time: $elapsed_time5 seconds"


test6.sh
#!/bin/bash
echo "TEST 6 START"
start_time6=$(date +%s)

for i in {1..100}; do
  curl -X GET "http://localhost:8080/test/${i}/something" &
done

wait

end_time6=$(date +%s)

elapsed_time6=$((end_time6 - start_time6))

echo "TEST 6 - Elapsed time: $elapsed_time6 seconds"


Build
mvn clean package

Run
java -jar target/app.jar

Run Test
test-main.sh

Result
You can count,

getTest passes in the parameter id from 1 to 100, and each number is called 2 times (test1.sh, test4.sh)

deleteTest passes in the parameter id from 1 to 100, and each number is called 2 times (test2.sh, test5.sh)

getTestSomething passes in the parameter id from 1 to 100, and each number is called 2 times (test3.sh, test6.sh)


TEST MAIN START
TEST 3 START
TEST 2 START
TEST 1 START
TEST 4 START
TEST 5 START
TEST 6 START
2024-09-26 20:05:44.372 get test: 67
2024-09-26 20:05:44.371 get test: 100
2024-09-26 20:05:44.345 get test: 90
2024-09-26 20:05:44.371 get test: 42
...
2024-09-26 20:05:44.762 get test: 76
2024-09-26 20:05:44.765 get test: 41
2024-09-26 20:05:44.769 get test: 31
2024-09-26 20:05:54.344 delete test: 72
2024-09-26 20:05:54.344 delete test: 46
2024-09-26 20:05:54.346 get test something: 43
2024-09-26 20:05:54.346 delete test: 77
2024-09-26 20:05:54.344 delete test: 1
...
2024-09-26 20:06:04.763 delete test: 19
2024-09-26 20:06:04.765 get test something: 27
2024-09-26 20:06:04.765 get test something: 29
2024-09-26 20:06:04.765 delete test: 25
2024-09-26 20:06:04.764 get test something: 95
TEST 5 - Elapsed time: 21 seconds
TEST 6 - Elapsed time: 21 seconds
TEST 2 - Elapsed time: 21 seconds
2024-09-26 20:06:04.780 get test something: 3
TEST 3 - Elapsed time: 21 seconds
TEST MAIN - Elapsed time: 21 seconds


app.log
You can check the http-nio-8080-exec-XX in app.log like http-nio-8080-exec-36 to see the processed Thread.
...
2024-09-26 20:05:44,340 [http-nio-8080-exec-36] INFO  com.example.HelloController                        - get test: 54
2024-09-26 20:05:44,342 [http-nio-8080-exec-47] INFO  com.example.HelloController                        - entry delete test: 46
2024-09-26 20:05:44,342 [http-nio-8080-exec-12] INFO  com.example.HelloController                        - entry delete test: 1
2024-09-26 20:05:44,342 [http-nio-8080-exec-51] INFO  com.example.HelloController                        - entry delete test: 72
2024-09-26 20:05:44,343 [http-nio-8080-exec-46] INFO  com.example.HelloController                        - get test: 64
2024-09-26 20:05:44,640 [http-nio-8080-exec-111] INFO  com.example.HelloController                        - entry get test something: 94
2024-09-26 20:05:44,652 [http-nio-8080-exec-109] INFO  com.example.HelloController                        - get test: 16
...
2024-09-26 20:05:44,728 [http-nio-8080-exec-174] INFO  com.example.HelloController                        - entry get test something: 86
2024-09-26 20:05:44,728 [http-nio-8080-exec-168] INFO  com.example.HelloController                        - get test: 21
2024-09-26 20:05:44,729 [http-nio-8080-exec-158] INFO  com.example.HelloController                        - entry get test something: 44
2024-09-26 20:05:44,729 [http-nio-8080-exec-165] INFO  com.example.HelloController                        - entry delete test: 88
2024-09-26 20:05:44,725 [http-nio-8080-exec-148] INFO  com.example.HelloController                        - entry get test something: 41
2024-09-26 20:05:44,727 [http-nio-8080-exec-160] INFO  com.example.HelloController                        - get test: 51
...
2024-09-26 20:05:54,638 [http-nio-8080-exec-107] INFO  com.example.HelloController                        - entry delete test: 89
2024-09-26 20:05:54,640 [http-nio-8080-exec-105] INFO  com.example.HelloController                        - get test something: 93
2024-09-26 20:05:54,642 [http-nio-8080-exec-111] INFO  com.example.HelloController                        - get test something: 94
2024-09-26 20:05:54,643 [http-nio-8080-exec-104] INFO  com.example.HelloController                        - get test: 58
...
2024-09-26 20:05:54,707 [http-nio-8080-exec-139] INFO  com.example.HelloController                        - delete test: 46
2024-09-26 20:05:54,708 [http-nio-8080-exec-153] INFO  com.example.HelloController                        - get test: 47
2024-09-26 20:05:54,709 [http-nio-8080-exec-124] INFO  com.example.HelloController                        - entry delete test: 57
2024-09-26 20:05:54,692 [http-nio-8080-exec-130] INFO  com.example.HelloController                        - delete test: 97
2024-09-26 20:05:54,692 [http-nio-8080-exec-141] INFO  com.example.HelloController                        - get test something: 83
2024-09-26 20:05:54,693 [http-nio-8080-exec-122] INFO  com.example.HelloController                        - get test something: 100
2024-09-26 20:05:54,693 [http-nio-8080-exec-127] INFO  com.example.HelloController                        - entry delete test: 26
2024-09-26 20:05:54,710 [http-nio-8080-exec-156] INFO  com.example.HelloController                        - get test something: 90
2024-09-26 20:05:54,710 [http-nio-8080-exec-153] INFO  com.example.HelloController                        - entry get test something: 76
2024-09-26 20:05:54,711 [http-nio-8080-exec-162] INFO  com.example.HelloController                        - delete test: 99
2024-09-26 20:05:54,712 [http-nio-8080-exec-156] INFO  com.example.HelloController                        - get test: 49
2024-09-26 20:05:54,712 [http-nio-8080-exec-122] INFO  com.example.HelloController                        - entry delete test: 43
2024-09-26 20:05:54,712 [http-nio-8080-exec-162] INFO  com.example.HelloController                        - get test: 9
2024-09-26 20:05:54,693 [http-nio-8080-exec-136] INFO  com.example.HelloController                        - get test something: 42
2024-09-26 20:05:54,693 [http-nio-8080-exec-116] INFO  com.example.HelloController                        - entry delete test: 64
2024-09-26 20:05:54,693 [http-nio-8080-exec-123] INFO  com.example.HelloController                        - delete test: 12
2024-09-26 20:05:54,713 [http-nio-8080-exec-147] INFO  com.example.HelloController                        - get test something: 64
...
2024-09-26 20:05:54,724 [http-nio-8080-exec-138] INFO  com.example.HelloController                        - entry get test something: 28
2024-09-26 20:05:54,724 [http-nio-8080-exec-166] INFO  com.example.HelloController                        - entry delete test: 86
2024-09-26 20:05:54,695 [http-nio-8080-exec-144] INFO  com.example.HelloController                        - get test something: 30
2024-09-26 20:05:54,696 [http-nio-8080-exec-143] INFO  com.example.HelloController                        - delete test: 48
2024-09-26 20:05:54,697 [http-nio-8080-exec-149] INFO  com.example.HelloController                        - delete test: 17
2024-09-26 20:05:54,726 [http-nio-8080-exec-170] INFO  com.example.HelloController                        - get test something: 85
2024-09-26 20:05:54,727 [http-nio-8080-exec-146] INFO  com.example.HelloController                        - get test something: 50
2024-09-26 20:05:54,727 [http-nio-8080-exec-149] INFO  com.example.HelloController                        - get test: 36
2024-09-26 20:05:54,697 [http-nio-8080-exec-135] INFO  com.example.HelloController                        - get test something: 18
2024-09-26 20:05:54,728 [http-nio-8080-exec-170] INFO  com.example.HelloController                        - get test: 97
2024-09-26 20:05:54,728 [http-nio-8080-exec-173] INFO  com.example.HelloController                        - delete test: 74
2024-09-26 20:05:54,728 [http-nio-8080-exec-159] INFO  com.example.HelloController                        - delete test: 75
2024-09-26 20:05:54,729 [http-nio-8080-exec-142] INFO  com.example.HelloController                        - entry get test something: 71
2024-09-26 20:05:54,732 [http-nio-8080-exec-159] INFO  com.example.HelloController                        - get test: 75
2024-09-26 20:05:54,732 [http-nio-8080-exec-143] INFO  com.example.HelloController                        - entry delete test: 35
2024-09-26 20:05:54,732 [http-nio-8080-exec-135] INFO  com.example.HelloController                        - entry get test something: 30
2024-09-26 20:05:54,697 [http-nio-8080-exec-114] INFO  com.example.HelloController                        - get test: 46
2024-09-26 20:05:54,732 [http-nio-8080-exec-146] INFO  com.example.HelloController                        - entry get test something: 16
2024-09-26 20:05:54,698 [http-nio-8080-exec-152] INFO  com.example.HelloController                        - get test something: 4
2024-09-26 20:05:54,733 [http-nio-8080-exec-169] INFO  com.example.HelloController                        - get test something: 93
2024-09-26 20:05:54,707 [http-nio-8080-exec-154] INFO  com.example.HelloController                        - get test: 46
2024-09-26 20:05:54,734 [http-nio-8080-exec-114] INFO  com.example.HelloController                        - get test: 81
2024-09-26 20:05:54,710 [http-nio-8080-exec-139] INFO  com.example.HelloController                        - get test: 84
2024-09-26 20:05:54,735 [http-nio-8080-exec-168] INFO  com.example.HelloController                        - get test something: 52
2024-09-26 20:05:54,712 [http-nio-8080-exec-141] INFO  com.example.HelloController                        - entry get test something: 81
2024-09-26 20:05:54,735 [http-nio-8080-exec-114] INFO  com.example.HelloController                        - entry get test something: 49
2024-09-26 20:05:54,735 [http-nio-8080-exec-176] INFO  com.example.HelloController                        - get test something: 76
2024-09-26 20:05:54,735 [http-nio-8080-exec-177] INFO  com.example.HelloController                        - delete test: 9
2024-09-26 20:05:54,735 [http-nio-8080-exec-139] INFO  com.example.HelloController                        - get test: 57
2024-09-26 20:05:54,735 [http-nio-8080-exec-154] INFO  com.example.HelloController                        - entry delete test: 69
2024-09-26 20:05:54,712 [http-nio-8080-exec-130] INFO  com.example.HelloController                        - entry get test something: 97
2024-09-26 20:05:54,736 [http-nio-8080-exec-152] INFO  com.example.HelloController                        - get test: 30
2024-09-26 20:05:54,736 [http-nio-8080-exec-155] INFO  com.example.HelloController                        - delete test: 74
2024-09-26 20:05:54,736 [http-nio-8080-exec-151] INFO  com.example.HelloController                        - get test something: 27
2024-09-26 20:05:54,737 [http-nio-8080-exec-176] INFO  com.example.HelloController                        - get test: 62
2024-09-26 20:05:54,737 [http-nio-8080-exec-180] INFO  com.example.HelloController                        - delete test: 71
2024-09-26 20:05:54,738 [http-nio-8080-exec-155] INFO  com.example.HelloController                        - entry delete test: 87
2024-09-26 20:05:54,738 [http-nio-8080-exec-172] INFO  com.example.HelloController                        - delete test: 87
2024-09-26 20:05:54,739 [http-nio-8080-exec-181] INFO  com.example.HelloController                        - get test something: 6
2024-09-26 20:05:54,739 [http-nio-8080-exec-184] INFO  com.example.HelloController                        - delete test: 65
2024-09-26 20:05:54,739 [http-nio-8080-exec-182] INFO  com.example.HelloController                        - delete test: 70
2024-09-26 20:05:54,740 [http-nio-8080-exec-185] INFO  com.example.HelloController                        - delete test: 53
2024-09-26 20:05:54,740 [http-nio-8080-exec-182] INFO  com.example.HelloController                        - get test: 28
2024-09-26 20:05:54,741 [http-nio-8080-exec-178] INFO  com.example.HelloController                        - delete test: 98
2024-09-26 20:05:54,741 [http-nio-8080-exec-188] INFO  com.example.HelloController                        - delete test: 50
2024-09-26 20:05:54,742 [http-nio-8080-exec-163] INFO  com.example.HelloController                        - delete test: 66
2024-09-26 20:05:54,742 [http-nio-8080-exec-151] INFO  com.example.HelloController                        - entry get test something: 69
2024-09-26 20:05:54,742 [http-nio-8080-exec-182] INFO  com.example.HelloController                        - entry get test something: 23
2024-09-26 20:05:54,742 [http-nio-8080-exec-180] INFO  com.example.HelloController                        - get test: 49
2024-09-26 20:05:54,743 [http-nio-8080-exec-163] INFO  com.example.HelloController                        - entry get test something: 68
2024-09-26 20:05:54,743 [http-nio-8080-exec-187] INFO  com.example.HelloController                        - delete test: 82
2024-09-26 20:05:54,743 [http-nio-8080-exec-177] INFO  com.example.HelloController                        - entry delete test: 62
2024-09-26 20:05:54,745 [http-nio-8080-exec-181] INFO  com.example.HelloController                        - entry get test something: 34
2024-09-26 20:05:54,714 [http-nio-8080-exec-162] INFO  com.example.HelloController                        - entry get test something: 67
2024-09-26 20:05:54,720 [http-nio-8080-exec-136] INFO  com.example.HelloController                        - entry get test something: 72
2024-09-26 20:05:54,730 [http-nio-8080-exec-158] INFO  com.example.HelloController                        - get test something: 44
2024-09-26 20:05:54,730 [http-nio-8080-exec-165] INFO  com.example.HelloController                        - delete test: 88
2024-09-26 20:05:54,747 [http-nio-8080-exec-195] INFO  com.example.HelloController                        - get test something: 17
2024-09-26 20:05:54,747 [http-nio-8080-exec-196] INFO  com.example.HelloController                        - delete test: 68
2024-09-26 20:05:54,747 [http-nio-8080-exec-165] INFO  com.example.HelloController                        - entry get test something: 48
2024-09-26 20:05:54,747 [http-nio-8080-exec-158] INFO  com.example.HelloController                        - entry get test something: 86
2024-09-26 20:05:54,730 [http-nio-8080-exec-173] INFO  com.example.HelloController                        - entry delete test: 33
2024-09-26 20:05:54,730 [http-nio-8080-exec-148] INFO  com.example.HelloController                        - get test something: 41
2024-09-26 20:05:54,730 [http-nio-8080-exec-144] INFO  com.example.HelloController                        - get test: 38
2024-09-26 20:05:54,748 [http-nio-8080-exec-195] INFO  com.example.HelloController                        - entry get test something: 87
2024-09-26 20:05:54,749 [http-nio-8080-exec-148] INFO  com.example.HelloController                        - entry delete test: 33
2024-09-26 20:05:54,749 [http-nio-8080-exec-196] INFO  com.example.HelloController                        - get test: 43
2024-09-26 20:05:54,730 [http-nio-8080-exec-150] INFO  com.example.HelloController                        - get test: 89
2024-09-26 20:05:54,730 [http-nio-8080-exec-170] INFO  com.example.HelloController                        - entry get test something: 15
2024-09-26 20:05:54,724 [http-nio-8080-exec-132] INFO  com.example.HelloController                        - entry get test something: 47
2024-09-26 20:05:54,731 [http-nio-8080-exec-161] INFO  com.example.HelloController                        - delete test: 90
2024-09-26 20:05:54,751 [http-nio-8080-exec-196] INFO  com.example.HelloController                        - get test: 70
2024-09-26 20:05:54,751 [http-nio-8080-exec-150] INFO  com.example.HelloController                        - entry get test something: 19
2024-09-26 20:05:54,731 [http-nio-8080-exec-160] INFO  com.example.HelloController                        - get test something: 53
2024-09-26 20:05:54,731 [http-nio-8080-exec-145] INFO  com.example.HelloController                        - entry delete test: 58
2024-09-26 20:06:04,763 [http-nio-8080-exec-161] INFO  com.example.HelloController                        - get test something: 27
2024-09-26 20:06:04,765 [http-nio-8080-exec-168] INFO  com.example.HelloController                        - delete test: 25
2024-09-26 20:06:04,765 [http-nio-8080-exec-186] INFO  com.example.HelloController                        - get test something: 29
2024-09-26 20:06:04,780 [http-nio-8080-exec-192] INFO  com.example.HelloController                        - get test something: 3

I don't see what's wrong?
